# RabbitMQ routing, topics and distributing work

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp

I am writing a system with RabbitMQ. I already use it for *work queues*, as described in their [tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html). Very easy and straightforward. When we publish a message to a queue, I know who will take care of it: producers and consumers are coupled (which was ok until now) in a one to one relationship.

I now want to do more complex stuff (n-m relationships between consumers and producers) :

- Producers publish a message, not knowing what will be done with it. (sending events)
- different Consumers types doing different stuff on a same message (for instance, statistics and logging)
- we can have several instances of a Consumers type running (let's say 3 statistics consumers and 2 logging consumers)
- every message can be processed by all Consumers types
- every message must be processed once by every Consumers type (competing consumers)

As I read the documentation, I am not sure how to implement it, especially the last point (competing consumers) I mentioned. I am confused about routing keys, topics and exchanges. For monitoring needs, I would like to have predictable queue names.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am not sure whether this question is the same or not, especially for the "every message must be processed once by every Consumers type" part of my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686868/rabbitmq-amqp-queue-design

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways to do this:

1)
You create a single "topic" exchange to route all your events.
You create one queue for every consumer type and bind them using routing key (like "type1", "type2", etc.).
Logging queue could be binded with routing key "#", meaning it'll receive all messages.
Different instances of the same consumer type should listen to single queue. This way they will act as "competing consumers", meaning each message will be processed by one instance of consumer (but you still have to make consuming idempotent).

2)
Similar to #1. But you create one "fanout" exchange for each message type, and then bind queues to them. Logging queue have to be binded to each exchange obviously. This is a preferred (idiomatic even) approach as it's faster and allows for better control.